# I am developing app with Azure functions using javascript, can I use wrappers or decorator techniques while writing javascript functions? I yes. How?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

## Example - *something like this*.

### wrapper.js

```
wrapper(originalFunction){
    let startTime = Date.now()
    originalFunction(this, arguments)
    let executionTime = Date.now() - startTime
    console.log("ExecutionTime=", executionTime)
}
```

### AzureFunction_1.js

```
module.exports = wrapperFunction(async function(){
    ...
    ...
    context.done()
})
```

I want to do this to add 1. logging, 2. global Error Handling, 3. executionTime, etc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To add the decorators to the azure functions, you need to set the experimentalDecorators flag in your tsconfig.json file to true as mentioned here in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

Also, refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299880/azure-functions-typescript-decorator/55362785#55362785) answer for creating custom decorator.